# Block element from showing when focus briefly lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, show-hide

I have a page with an `iFrame` on it.  For the visitor, it's important for them to know if the `iFrame` has the focus of the browser or not.

To achieve this, when the page loads the `iFrame` is given focus.  If focus is lost, a div `overlay` is displayed over the top of the `iFrame` letting them know focus is lost.  If the `overlay` is clicked, it's hidden and focus is given back to `iframe`:

```
// When overlay is clicked, focus on game
$('#NoFocusOverlay').click(function () {
    focusOnGame();
});

// When game loses focus, show overlay
$('#GameIFrame').blur(function () {
    $('#NoFocusOverlay').fadeIn('fast');
});

function focusOnGame() {
    $('#GameIFrame').focus();
    $('#NoFocusOverlay').hide();
}
```

Now the problem is, there are some controls on the page (volume adjustment, change size of iframe etc) that when clicked need to give focus back to the `iFrame`:

```
// Change volume of game via control on page
function changeVol(newVol){
    ... do vol change...
    focusOnGame();
}
```

The problem is, when you click the volume control focus is lost, it briefly shows the overlay before focus is re-established and the overlay is hidden.  It doesn't look good the overlay keeping flashing up, is there any way to stop this happening easily?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put an if statement in here?

```
$('#GameIFrame').blur(function () {
    if (The Control ID DOES NOT HAVE Focus){
    $('#NoFocusOverlay').fadeIn('fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you using to decide if the controls have focus? Also, there could be a way to consider the controls part of the game itself, so it technically doesn't lose focus... that is, if there's no page space between the controls and the game window.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this.  Order of click() events is important so that the document click event fires after the wrapper click:

```
// Preserve order
var blockOverlay = false;
$('.game-outer-wrap').click(function () {
    blockOverlay = true;
});
$(document).click(function () {
    if (!blockOverlay) {
        $('#NoFocusOverlay').fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
        focusOnGame();
    }
    blockOverlay = false;
});
function focusOnGame() {
    $('#GameIFrame').focus();
    $('#NoFocusOverlay').hide();
}
```